# UINavigationControllerDelegate's methods is not enough

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

The `UINavigationControllerDelegate` only has 2 delegation methods to use:

- `navigationController:willShowViewController:`
- `navigationController:didShowViewController:`

But what if I want to be called when I pop the viewController interactively using gesture? Something like:

- `navigationController:willStartDragging:`
- `navigationController:isDraggingWithPercentage:`

There are no delegation methods like this in the protocol. How can I get these methods?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a target/action to the navigation controller's `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` like this:

```
[navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(handleInteractivePop:)];
```

And then keep track of the state of the gesture

```
- (void)handleInteractivePop:(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    switch (recognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            // Started Dragging
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            CGFloat percentComplete = [recognizer locationInView:yourView].x / yourView.frame.size.width;
            // Do something
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            // Released
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```